# How to use the __bzhi_uxx intrinsic without letting gcc to insert other BMI2 instructions everywhere?

Tags: gcc, intrinsics, built-in

I would like to use the `_bzhi_u32` intrinsic but I don't want to use the `-mbmi2` flag since that makes `gcc` to use other BMI2 instruction (notably `SHLX` in many `<<` shifts) which will produce `SIGILL` (Illegal instruction) if the host where the executable runs doesn't not support BMI2.

I only use `_bzhi_u32` in one function and I guard  it's use by checking at runtime that is supported via `_builtin_cpu_is("corei7")` defaulting to another implementation if not supported. But I cannot guard the other BMI2 instruction that gcc inserts when `-mbmi2` is used.

The problem is that the `_bzhi_u32` intrinsic won't be defined in `x86intrin.h` unless `-mbmi2` is specified (with the undesired effect of gcc sprinkling `SHLX` all over the place).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible alternatives to avoid specifying `-mbmi2` globally

1. If using GCC 4.9 or higher, you can just include `x86intrin.h` and declare the function use `_bzhi_u32` with `__attribute__((target ("bmi2")))`. That way gcc will generate BMI2 instruction on that function. **This doesn't work on 4.8 and lower** (`_bzhi_u32` is not defined unless `__BMI2__` is set and even if it is the linker will complain with `undefined reference to '_bzhi_u32'`).
2. Put the definition of the function in its own `.c` file and put `#pragma GCC target "bmi2"` at the top. This defines `__BMI2__` and enables BMI2 instruction generation for this translation unit only.
3. Put the function in its own file like option 2 and compile with `-mbmi2` just that file (which is equivalent to the `#pragma GCC target` option.
4. Use inline assembly instead of intrinsics as explained in this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32259581/90580).

Options 2 and 3 limits your `inline` and `static` options. Option 1 is the way to go if you are using GCC 4.9 or higher.

Comment: If you add `#define __BMI2__` and `__attribute__((target ("bmi2")))`, linking should not be an issue.  The intrinsics are emitted by the compiler.

Comment: Well, if you are using gcc 4.8 like I'm using, linking is an issue. I can see that they fixed that in gcc 4.9. Quoting from the [Release Notes][https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html]: "It is now possible to call x86 intrinsics from select functions in a file that are tagged with the corresponding target attribute without having to compile the entire file with the -mxxx option.". I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: You should not define `__BMI2__`, whatever your version of gcc.

Comment: The assembler is simple enough that it may not be worth using the intrinsic if the compiler won't emit correct code.  I've added an answer with an example.

Comment: I wanted to use intrinsics to avoid learning inline assembly but it turns out to be easier that I thought it will be, thanks for the example.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from [gcc 4.9 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html):

> It is now possible to call x86 intrinsics from select functions in a
>   file that are tagged with the corresponding target attribute without
>   having to compile the entire file with the -mxxx option. This improves
>   the usability of x86 intrinsics and is particularly useful when doing
>   Function Multiversioning.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the intrinsic, it may be easier to embed the assembler code...

```
uint32_t val, i;

asm ("bzhi %0,%1,%2" : "=r"(val) : "r"(val), "r"(i) : );
```

Comment: yes, although I was trying to avoid inline assembly. But it's good to mention that there are alternatives to intrinsics

Comment: It might be easier to write (or to copy/paste), but the compiler doesn't understand what this does, so it defeats optimizations like constant-propagation.  Don't suggest this without appropriate cautionary notes, e.g. **https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm**